# How to check if JqxGrid has any errors?

Tags: html, css, jqwidget

In the below code, i am showing borders highlighted if there are any validation failure and that is working fine 
Is there any way to check if validation errors on Grid on clicking a button?
Click the button at bottom and there i would like identify if there are any errors

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KHrm/212/)

Code

```
 $('#jqxbutton').click(function () {
 alert("Here i would like check if there are any errors in the grid");});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed find if there are any errors by finding the elements with class 'errorcolumn' with jquery.find. 
i dont think jqwidgets provides any api